# AWS Boto describe instances spot vs on demand vs reserved

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Maybe I'm blind, but I'm not seeing the metadata indicating if the instance is spot, on demand or reserved.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

for instance in instances:
    print instance.(?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [describe_instances](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

**spot_instance_request_id** - The ID of the Spot instance request.

- If `spot_instance_request_id` is not empty, then it is spot instance

There is no way to check if the instance is reserved. AWS doesn't mark any instance as reserved. Your bill varies depending on your instance reservations and instance usage.

```
for instance in instances:
   if instance.spot_instance_request_id:
     print instance.instance_id, 'is a SPOT instance'
   else:
     print instance.instance_id, 'is not a SPOT instance'
```

Comment: Is there any way to find out if an instance is reserved? or On-Demand?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign no, there is no way. AWS checks the number of on demand instances that are running, subtracts the instances that are reserved and then calculates the charge for the rest of the instances. So there is no way to find out if an instance is reserved or on demand.