# Turn on All ec2(+ future created ec2) 'termination protection' Using Lambda

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Im trying to turn on 'termination protection' for all ec2.
(termination protection doesn't work to spot instance, so i want to add skip condition not to make an error for spot instance.)

I saw a code like below, however the code doesn't work.

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  client = boto3.client('ec2')
  ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
  for region in ec2_regions:
     client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
     conn = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
     instances = conn.instances.filter()
     for instance in instances:
       if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
       #print instance.id # , instance.instance_type, region)
        terminate_protection=client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId =instance.id,Attribute = 'disableApiTermination')
        protection_value=(terminate_protection['DisableApiTermination']['Value'])
        if protection_value == False:
          client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance.id,Attribute="disableApiTermination",Value= "True" )
```

Summary,,,
I want to turn on 'Termination protection' for all EC2 which is running(not spot instance).
The region should be ap-northeast-2.

Could you help me to fix this code to running appropriatly?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code doesn't work"?

Comment: Why is the last line setting the `disableApiTermination` attribute to False? This would deactivate Termination Protection.

Comment: The reason why i said the code doesn't work is I want to skip the spot instance when running this code, but fail. ```error message```: ```"An error occurred (UnsupportedOperation) when calling the ModifyInstanceAttribute operation: Modifying 'disableApiTermination' is not supported for spot instances.", ``` 


Also, you right, the last line should be changed 'True'. The key point is i want to skip the spot instance,

Comment: For example, i have 2 ondemand instance, 1 spot instance.
so, im trying to run the lambda code to enable termination protection only to ondemand instance.

Comment: posted a solution did it worked?

Comment: I solved the problem. Really appreciate all your supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to skip the spot instance all you need to do this is figure out which one is spot instance.

You need to use `describe_instances` api and then  using if-else condition, request_id is empty its a spot instance, if not then its not a spot instance

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}]) #add filter of your own choice
for instance in instances:
   if instance.spot_instance_request_id:
     # logic to skip termination ( spot instance ) 
   else:
     # logic to terminate ( not spot instance )
```

You can refer a similar question on this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604396/13126651

docs for [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

Comment: Thank you, i tested the code and it worked well.